# integers aren't working properly in a comparison

Tags: java

I'm currently in grade 12 computer science so sorry if the solution is super obvious but my teacher couldn't figure it out either.
so basically the program is supposed to take four user inputs for the tire pressure, then if the front 2 aren't equal, or the back 2 aren't equal, or any tire isn't within a certain range, it will output text telling you what's wrong. it does tell you if the front or back isn't equal, but it doesn't tell you if any of them are out of range.

```
class TireCheck{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(inStream);
        String frontLeft, frontRight, backLeft, backRight;
        
        System.out.println("Enter front left tire pressure:"); //asks for user input
        frontLeft = stdin.readLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter front right tire pressure:"); //asks for user input
        frontRight = stdin.readLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter back left tire pressure:"); //asks for user input
        backLeft = stdin.readLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter back right tire pressure:"); //asks for user input
        backRight = stdin.readLine();
        
        int FrontLeft = Integer.parseInt(frontLeft);
        int FrontRight = Integer.parseInt(frontRight);
        int BackLeft = Integer.parseInt(backLeft);
        int BackRight = Integer.parseInt(backRight);
        
        if( FrontLeft >= 32 && FrontLeft <= 38 ){
            System.out.println("Tire out of range: front left");
        }
        if(FrontRight >= 32 && FrontRight <= 38){
            System.out.println("Tire out of range: front right");
        }
        if(BackLeft >= 32 && BackLeft <= 38){
            System.out.println("Tire out of range: back left");
        }
        if(BackRight >= 32 && BackRight <= 38){
            System.out.println("Tire out of range: back right");
        }
        if(FrontLeft != FrontRight){
            System.out.println("Tire inflation is not equal: front");
        }
        if(BackLeft != BackRight){
            System.out.println("Tire inflation is not equal: back");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "out of range".  Those conditions look like they're checking if something is *in* range.  For example, if you enter the value `35` for `FrontLeft` then `if(FrontLeft >= 32 && FrontLeft <= 38)` is `true` because `35` is in that defined range.  What values are you entering and what output are you expecting?

Comment: It does tell you if the numbers are out of range. Its just that you defined out of range to be anthing from 32 to 38. So a pressure of 1 or 3 billion will be in range, but a pressure of 34 will be out of range. You most likely just mixed up `<` and `>` and or `&&` with `||` when defining your ranges.

Comment: Welcome, KeninCrime, to StackOverflow. Please try to make your question more relavant to your real issue. All these tires and texts are not needed. Please reduce your program and problem description so it talks only about the very part which is wrong.

Comment: Assuming 38 is the maximum pressure and anything between 32 and 38 could potentially cause blowout, the logic you have is correct. What values are you entering for each input request?

Comment: What are your inputs and what are the outputs for them; can you add an input/output example? It will help us all to understand and find a solution for problem

Comment: Java naming conventions have variables and methods start with a lower case using camelCase. This makes it easier to identify variables when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: How about you change all

`if(VALUE >= 32 && VALUE <= 38)`

to

`if(VALUE < 32 || VALUE > 38)`?

Comment: Probably strictly less than/greater than, as opposed to lte/gte.

Comment: @paladin good idea but mistaken. The opposite of `(VALUE >= 32 && VALUE <= 38)` is actually `(VALUE < 32 || VALUE > 38)`

Comment: Fixed it. Thx, posted it too fast :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's run some tests for the logic you have.

User enters:

```
Front Left: 30
Front Right: 31
Back Left: 30
Back Right: 31

output: 
Tire inflation is not equal: front
Tire inflation is not equal: back
```

No range output because those numbers are in range.

```
Front Left: 32
Front Right: 32
Back Left: 32
Back Right: 32

output: 
Tire out of range: front left
Tire out of range: front right
Tire out of range: back left
Tire out of range: back right
```

No `inflation is not equal` output because obviously they are all equal

```
Front Left: 36
Front Right: 38
Back Left: 40
Back Right: 40

output: 
Tire out of range: front left
Tire out of range: front right
Tire inflation is not equal: front
```

Back tire pressures are equal so no `inflation is not equal` output.  Although back tires are above 38, they are considered in range for this logic.

```
Front Left: 45
Front Right: 45
Back Left: 29
Back Right: 29
```

No output